# Hive multiple joins failing

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I'm running the following query on hive,

`SELECT a, b, c, d, e 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.a = B.a
JOIN C ON A.b = C.a
LIMIT 10;`

I keep getting the following error,

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Column a Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries
```

Comment: use the tablename/alias if the column is present in more than one table..which is `a` in this case per the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have more than one table in a query, qualify *all* column names:

```
SELECT a.a, ?.b, ?.c, ?.d, ?.e 
FROM A JOIN
     B 
     ON A.a = B.a JOIN
     C 
     ON A.b = C.a
LIMIT 10;
```

The `?` is for the tables where those columns come from.  ALso, it is a bit unorthodox to use `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`.